# Why isn't anything playing when the rate is 1.0?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am trying to play a song from a link using the avkit, but nothin is being played. I used an online mp3 file to link converter to generate a link. If anyone has a better method to convert an mp3 file to a link I am all ears. Apart from that the real problem I'm having is why I can't hear anything. I have a feeling it's the link and it is not supported. Keep in mind that `playedSong` is being called in the viewDidLoad. [Link to the song I am trying to play](http://picosong.com/ANQY)

```
var urlPath = "http://picosong.com/ANQY"

func playedSong(){
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    player.play()
    player.rate = 1.0
    if(player.rate == 1.0){
        print(url)//prints correct url
        print("playing")//prints
    }else{
        print("not playing")
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a link to a page that plays: `/cdn/3ad39f5ed1822a978f8463d631f65f18.mp3` - not the actual mp3 file itself

Comment: I knew it was the link, how would I play the actual mp3 file through just a link?

Comment: They probably have it hidden behind the web somewhere so you might not be able to - it's impossible to say where it is as their .htaccess (or something similar) file could send the request anywhere

Comment: hmm ok so ditching the link I provided do you happen to know of a reliable method I can use in converting an mp3 to a link?

Comment: You simply need the path of an mp3 file - e.g. `http://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/india-national-anthem.mp3`

Comment: Yeah but it can't be a local directory path it obviously has to be somewhere on the internet like with the link you provided me. Like if I have a downloaded song on my machine I need to convert that into a link to play

Comment: Then you need to upload it to somewhere which will then give you the link you need - or if you are developing locally then something like `http://localhost/mySongs/myFile.mp3`

Comment: That makes much more sense.

Comment: Would I need to create my own web server or are there any services that help with this?

Comment: Where are you developing the code? Locally or on a remotely? Either way, you're on a server which you can use